# Question regarding law of vector law of addition and its meaning in real life?

Tags: vectors

[image]

Refer the diagram above.

Q1 I am walking from AB to BC.We say I walked $\vec{a}$+ $\vec{b}$ = $\vec{c}$.As it’s addition.If we simply it in form of its magnitude.We say $a^2+b^2=c^2$. Then why do we say that magnitude of vector a is |a|=a?It can’t be a+b=c?

Q2 When I say $\cos\theta $in the diagram is x/b.Why don’t I say vector b or b^2. Since that is the magnitude.We can’t say a+b=c in terms of magnitude right?.It has to be square on them.

Comment: $|a|+|b|\neq|c|$ in general. For example, if $\vec{a}=-\vec{b}$ then $|a|+|b|=2|a|$ but $|c|=0$. Also $|a|^2+|b|^2=|c|^2$ is only true iff $a$ and $b$ are perpendicular.

Comment: Suppose your height is $h$, then your height is $h$. Your height is not $h^2$... squaring doesn't give you height... Your height is just $h$..

Comment: Don’t we say magnitude of a as $a^2$

Comment: Do we square because we know pythagoras theorem.

Comment: No. Magnitude of vector $a$ is represented as $|a|$. If the vector $a$ has coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$, then  the magnitude of vector $a$ is $\sqrt{{x_1}^2 + {y_1}^2}$

Comment: Also pythagoras theorem is for `right` triangles. It doesn't work for other triangle types

Comment: When we say vector a + vector b = vector c.We only mean to find its displacement here.

Comment: What about distance.Is it that which comes by a +b and not a^2 + b^2.

Comment: Hmm  $a$ is name of vector. If the vector $a$ has coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$, then the magnitude of vector $a$ is $\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}$. This is also the `length` of vector $a$

Comment: I suggest you watch [this short video on khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-home/alg-vectors/alg-vector-basics/v/introduction-to-vectors-and-scalars?modal=1)

Comment: Ok.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user277768 no probs; feel free to ask if something still bothers you. but be specific so that answering is easier..